# Is it better to instantiate a new object, or simply update the attributes for new data?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it more efficient to update attributes or just instantiate a new object?

For example:

```
class Position(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def update_position(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def new_Position(self, message):
        self.update_position(message[0], message[1], message[2])

def new_Position(message):
    return Position(message[0], message[1], message[2])
```

Comment: Depends on how expensive the constructor of said class is.  This is really broad. It could be expensive either in memory or cpu. Also it depends on whether you really do want a new object or not.

Comment: What if it were the constructor shown in the example. At what point is it too expensive to do?

Comment: Also depends on what you plan to do with it. And you might be interested in [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: This question needs more of a specific use case for a decent answer. In your trivial example it is obviously more efficient to update the object instead of reserving more memory to construct a new object.

Comment: Chances are most of the time that updating attributes are more efficient. You can see in your example that attribute assignment occurs in the constructor anyway, along with the other work needed to create a new object.

Comment: It depends. Sometimes non-mutable objects are simply easier to use, and then you'll have to create new instances everytime. If you want a mutable object then you ought to update the attributes, if the user wants a new, different instance he can always create it "by hand" calling the constructor and taking the values from the old instance or using `copy.deepcopy`.
As other already stated, creating a new object is more expensive because python has to do a lot more things then just settings attributes, but I think that a design decision like this shouldn't be based only on micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

**You shouldn't do premature optimization**, the choice between an update method and some sort of factory function is mainly a design choice.

Anyway, out of curiosity, here's the [disassembled](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis) code between the two calls:

```
>>> p = Position(1,2,3)
>>> dis.dis(p.new_position)
 11           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (update_position)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (message)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             13 LOAD_FAST                1 (message)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             19 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             20 LOAD_FAST                1 (message)
             23 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             26 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             30 POP_TOP             
             31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(new_position)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Position)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (message)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             10 LOAD_FAST                0 (message)
             13 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             16 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             17 LOAD_FAST                0 (message)
             20 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             23 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             27 RETURN_VALUE
```